# app.locals and res.locals life cycle

Tags: node.js, express

I'm really confused by `app.locals` and `res.locals` because I don't know WHEN should I use them and how? And actually I want to know the `app.locals` and `res.locals` life cycle.

For example where should I save my user (authenticated user) details (username, roles etc.)? In `app.locals` or `res.locals`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can consider `app.locals` to be global. Some examples of things you might want to store in `app.locals`: URL helpers, application-level constants. You should put anything here that you want accessible in every single view.

`res.locals` stores data only for a particular response (which responds to a particular request). For example, GET /something will create a new res.locals that gets passed through all the middleware responding to '/something.' Appropriate information here is stuff like authenticated user details from your question.

The lifecycle looks like this, where your responsibilities **are bold** (everything else is done for you by express):

1. **app is created (var app = express();)**
2. app.locals is created
3. request arrives
4. res.locals is created for that request
5. **you add things to res.locals like user roles (res.locals.role = 'admin';)**
6. **you serve a response to the request (res.render('some/view');)**
7. res.locals for that request is garbage collected, gone
8. app.locals continues to exist as long as the app exists

Comment: How do you use the res.locals.role on the client? Is the role value accessed using {{role}} like other data?